# Threading in Python Sugggestions

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am currently trying to thread two loops in python. One is currently a tkinter loop that displays the the gui I have set up, and the other is a p2p chat function. using 'import threading', defining threads and starting them individually doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions for what method I can use to get these two loops running concurrently?

The code I'm using to start the threads:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=x.mainloop())
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop())
thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the functions *without* calling them. As is, you're trying to call them, and pass the return value as the `target` for the thread; since they never return, you never launch the second thread. Try:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=x.mainloop)  # Removed call parens on target
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop)  # Removed call parens on target
thread2.start()
```

Comment: That was part of the issue yeah, but I also learned Tkinter is "mainly based on single-threaded event model. The mainloop(), callbacks, event handlers and raising tkinter exceptions are all handled in single thread."